# Running a url using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a script/api which is suppose to add a record to my database when running a specific url. However i'm not sure how to run this url. I do not expect anything back just to run this url? how can i do this?

```
    var identifier = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
    var addViewUrl = "http://url/addview.php?type=ios&identifier=\(identifier)&newsid=\(newsObject?.id)"
```

Comment: You should expect some response. You should at least check if there was an error because your url could not be reached or your given parameters were wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comment:
You should get a response and check for errors.
Also there is always the possibility to call a URL `asynchronously` to avoid blocking the GUI if the request takes a long time.

This can be made using delegate patterns or with completions handlers like in Objective-C.

**Example:**

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString(addViewUrl)// Creating URL
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)// Creating Http Request

var queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{(response:NSURLResponse!, responseData:NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil
        {
            println(error.description)
        }
        else
        {
            var responseStr:NSString = NSString(data:responseData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            //Everything went fine
         }
    })
```

Comment: because i made a mistake. It should be if error != nil instead of if error == nil. Edited in the answer aswell.